# Range gives me something else in place of 0, why?

Tags: floating-point, range, wolfram-mathematica, numerical-stability

I wanted to put some `FrameTicks` to a `Plot` with

```
xticks = Range[-2, 2, 0.2]
```

and got

```
{-2., -1.8, -1.6, -1.4, -1.2, -1., -0.8, -0.6, -0.4, -0.2, 
1.11022*10^-16, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1., 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.}
```

so there is the small number instead of the zero.

Using `Table` gives the same output:

```
Table[k, {k, -2, 2, 0.2}]
{-2., -1.8, -1.6, -1.4, -1.2, -1., -0.8, -0.6, -0.4, -0.2, 
1.11022*10^-16, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1., 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.}
```

But using `0.25` as the step value, everything is fine:

```
xticks = Range[-2, 2, 0.25]
{-2., -1.75, -1.5, -1.25, -1., -0.75, -0.5, -0.25, 0., 0.25, 0.5, \
0.75, 1., 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.}
```

How to replace the small number and set it to zero?

Comment: FWIW Mathematica v9 actually is smart enough to handle this. What version do you have? (Both `Table` and `Range` give an exact zero ).  I would still advise using the approaches in @TobiaTesan answer however.

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR:

Consider using:

```
Range[-20, 20, 2]/10
```

optionally converting them to floating point with:

```
N[Range[-20, 20, 2]/10]`
```

---

### What's actually going on with the `0`:

`Range[-2, 2, 0.2]` uses floating point arithmetic, so at some point it gets to some `n` which is a floating point approximation of `-0.2` and adds `0.2f`: the result cannot possibly be `0` - we are in the domain **F** -, it can at best be `0.` or some other reasonably close approximant (see also: [The difference between `0.` and `0`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6994/the-difference-between-0-and-0)).

How close is "reasonably close", though?

[Floating point subtraction between really close values is notoriously tricky](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~bindel/class/cs6210-f12/notes/lec04.pdf), and **that's probably why `2.0, 1.8, ...` look fine but your approximant for zero, obtained by `-0.2f + 0.2f`, is *ugly***.

On the other hand, `Range[-20, 20, 2]` works with natural numbers and `-2 + 2` in **N** is plain `0` (fixed precision arithmetic is not nearly as tricky as floating point).

Then `Range[-20, 20, 2]/10` maps to **Q** (where any *p/q* with *p* = 0 still easily evaluates to 0).

You can also [chop](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html) your floats to arbitrary precision with `Chop[Range[-2, 2, 0.2]]`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. Now I see the difference of domains Real and Integer. 
The

Chop[Range[-2, 2, 0.2]]


works for me, because I wanted to have Numbers instead of fractions in my ticks.

Comment: @edwinbubble glad to help. Feel free to accept this answer by clicking on the v-tick icon :)

Comment: But I can't get the point why 0.25 works, while 0.2 doesn't? Both numbers are of the same kind, namely rational...

Comment: @edwinbubble: `0.2` "works" as well, `1.11022*10^-16` is a reasonably good approximant of *the* `0` - it is only `1.11022*10^-16` off from `0.`, after all :) Why the `0.25` sequence yields a marginally better approximation I can't say, you'd have to look at your hardware and at the exact (family of) algorithms Mathematica uses (e.g.: on my machine, I get `0.`). I think "blind luck" is a sufficiently good explanation, once we know *why* `0.2 - 0.2` is not that accurate. Note that `0.25` is `2^-2`, which is a very nice number to start with. If you are so inclined, make some experiments :)

Comment: not luck, .25 being a power of 2 is exactly represented in floating point

Comment: @agentp: yes, my point was that OP shouldn't probably overanalyze this, though - it's **not "broken"** :)

Comment: Thanks you both, now I got the point. Maybe I was over-analyzing, but I was just curious. Once understood one can go one...